# How can I redirect all pages from www to non-www and also http to https with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been able to find solutions to each of these redirects separately but I can't find something that does both correctly.

I need the website to redirect from:

```
http://somesite.com.au to https://somesite.com.au
http://www.somesite.com.au to https://somesite.com.au
https://www.somesite.com.au to https://somesite.com.au
```

The main combination that I'm having trouble with is:

```
https://www.somesite.com.au to https://somesite.com.au
```

Currently I am using the following in my htaccess file:

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on

# Ensure we are using HTTPS version of the site.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect www to non-ww
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What should I be using in my htaccess to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're causing a loop because your `www` rule redirects *to `http://`*. Just change it to redirect to `https://` instead:

```
# Redirect www to non-ww
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I just tried this and it's redirecting from http to https ok but redirecting from http www to https www

Comment: @kezzman11 you still have your other rule, right? And cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: Yes, I kept the other rule and also cleared my cache. I tried it on a different browser too but still no luck. The strange thing is that I had the correct combination of this redirect working at some stage yesterday but then this morning it's not working again.

Comment: I can't find a working solution for this so I am getting our SSL certificate re-issued and if users go to the www version they will just stay there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kezz after it gets redirected to `https://www` the other rule should get applied and you get redirected *again* from www to no www.

Comment: Your original code is working correctly now that the SSL has been issued to the www URL. Thanks again.